# Codeigniter ActiveRecord not showing all results

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

So I was trying to pull all the names from all the users from the database but I only get one, in this case the first result it finds in the table. Here's the code i'm trying:

```
public function getAllUsers(){

    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    $result = $query->result();

    foreach ($result as $record)
    {
       return $record->name;
    }

}
```

I've already tried a lot of convinations but to no avail. I'm using a var_dump to display it on the view. I've already tried to loop it in the vewi too but nothing happens. Any help?

**EDIT[SOLVED]** : The foreach in this case will loop and bring all the records but once it's done all the data is lost so in order to keep the data, I was suggested to create an empty array first, then set the data to the array within the loop and then return that array after the loop is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your foreach loop runs only one time and return data. You need to store your data into array and result

```
$data=array(); // define empty array
foreach ($result as $record)
    {
       $data[]= $record->name;// assign name to array
    }
    return $data;// return data
```

Comment: I've tried that but that brings only the last record in the table :(

Comment: Yup, thank you guys! this worked! not sure why though, why is this working?

Comment: After return type every thing is vanish . you need to store your data into array and return that after after your loop.

Comment: The method would also exit on the first loop. That return statement inside the loop would be useful in cases you need to find just one value in a given array.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public function getAllUsers(){
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    $result = $query->result();
    $name = array();
    foreach ($result as $record)
    {
       $name[] =  $record->name;
    }
    return $name ; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! same answer at the same time :) any explanation?

Comment: you were returning  `$record->name;`  so for the first record the function returned the first value and the loop could not proceed further.